# Is it possible to assembly loadfrom Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, .net-assembly, system.reflection, gettype

When i try this

```
    oAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("C:\dynamicdlls\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll")
    oType = oAssembly.GetType("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application")

    Try
        oObject = Activator.CreateInstance(oType)
        Dim doc As Object = oObject.Documents.Open("C:\worddoc\test.docx")

        Dim count As Integer = doc.Words.Count
        For i As Integer = 1 To count
            Dim text As String = doc.Words(i).Text
            Console.WriteLine("Word {0} = {1}", i, text)
        Next

        oObject.Quit()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

I get "Cannot create an instance of an interface".

**I Know there is a better alternative to this, I am just exploring this method and would like to know if this is possible and how would one do it.**

Comment: The problem is just as you see it, can't create an instance of an interface.  When you add a reference to the assembly then the compiler can tell that it is an interface and it will look for the [CoClass] attribute to find a way to call the factory function, Type.GetTypeFromCLSID() is involved.  That mechanism can't work when you do it like this.  Late-bound code looks very different, you use CreateObject().  There is very little point in making your life difficult.

Comment: Your code should work if you change `oAssembly.GetType("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application")` to `oAssembly.GetType("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass")`, but this is a strange way to get the Type.  I would recommend using: `Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.Application")` to retrieve the Type as it eliminates the interop assembly dependency.